# Why is %E2%80%8F being added to my Youtube embed code?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, iframe, youtube

I have a bunch of videos on Youtube which I embed using the same code.  All of the videos worked fine until I uploaded the last one.  Every time I now execute the code, %E2%80%8F is appended to the last uploaded video, unless I specifically ask for a substring(0,11); note that without this hack, the code still works fine for all of my other uploaded videos. And though the code now works with my hack, it would be great to understand why this could be happening.

My HTML markup looks like this:

```
<li><a href="#" class="help_video" id="oG-M25hnDII‏">sidebars</a></li>
```

My javascript/jquery looks like this:

```
function openNewWindow(youtube_link) {
var youtube_link = youtube_link.toString();

youtube_link = youtube_link.substring(0,11);
 popupWin = window.open('/videos/help.php?youtube_link='+youtube_link,
 'open_window',
 'menubar, toolbar, location, directories, status, scrollbars, resizable, dependent, width=800, height=440, left=0, top=0')
 }

$(".help_video").click(function(){
openNewWindow($(this).attr('id'));
return false;
});
 });
```

Then, my associated help.php has the following code:

```
<iframe width="756" height="426" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $_GET['youtube_link'];?>?rel=0&vq=hd720" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Thanks!

Comment: try looking up the ascii codes for `E2` etc.

Comment: I had already done this and know that the combination is "right to left".  I still see no reason why this would be added...

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6067808/weird-characters-such-as-x202a-x202c-rlm

Comment: I fear that I'm not quite sure how that would help in this situation.  Doesn't the $_GET automatically decode URL links?  (Regardless, I tried html_entity_decode, but without any improved effect) Any additional direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The link includes the right-to left mark UTF8 character

Take a look here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left_mark

This is a non-printing character, so you won't see it on screen, but your editor sneaked it in.

Try

- using another editor to write again this portion of code
- settting up your code editor to display special characters (tabs, newlines, etc). This way you'll be able to see and delete the rtl mark

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  I tried switching editors to show the invisible characters and the Right-to-left mark doesn't show up.  But, I wasn't even aware that I could see "invisible characters", hence the up vote.

Comment: I had the same issue. I converted my test to ANSI with notepad++ and saw this extra bytes converted as ?. I removed it and convert back my text to UTF8 and everything was good.

Answer (score 2):

[These instructions won't go in a "comment" but this is a comment to Tudor's answer. So if this works, please give him the bounty / answer]

In your edit, take the line

```
<li><a href="#" class="help_video" id="oG-M25hnDII‏">sidebars</a></li>
```

and select the following part with mouse of keyboard:

```
id="oG-M25hnDII‏">sidebars
```

then hit "delete" so you end up with

```
<li><a href="#" class="help_video" </a></li>
```

Save, Close file from editor, Open file in editor.

Put cursor before the `</a>` and type (**do not paste**, but manually type the code back in using the keyboard) so you end with where you started.

Save.

(Then, if this works, get a friendly editor)

Rob

Comment: I can't believe that this fixed it!  And, you are a true gentleman to give the bounty/answer to Tudor.  Also, thinking back to how I created the id in the first place, it was copy/pasted directly off of a Youtube link; so, if this does happen again, and I'd like to keep using my editor, the quick solution seems to be to just manually type in the Youtube video id instead of copy/pasting it.  Enjoy your weekend...