# Why is "%E2%80%8F" being appended to URL when I copy and paste URL from emails on Outlook?

Tags: url

Every time I copy and paste URL from Outlook email subjects, why is "%E2%80%8F" being appended to URL? Could this be a bug or intended side effect?

Why would this be needed for an email subject?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is %E2%80%8F being added to my Youtube embed code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21470476/why-is-e2808f-being-added-to-my-youtube-embed-code)

Comment: I'm curious about why this is necessary for an email subject? I see the issue with Youtube embed code arises from using an editor, in my case, I'm using the Outlook web client. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a right-to-left mark. It's used to change the way adjacent characters are grouped with respect to text direction, esp in mixed right/left, left/right scripts environments. It's "non-printing" hence why it's not visible "on screen" but is when you copy it link (though not all programs are as lazy as Outlook and handle it better).

The `U+200F` here: http://unicode.org/reports/tr9/ == `E2` `80` `8F`

Comment: Do you have an idea why Outlook needs to add this mark to the end of email subject? I can't think of how anyone would want to go from left to right for email subjects? It is also odd this issue has been there for so long.